# .NET 6 Using HTTP Client for API Calls within Web API Project Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am still new to .NET and have been using `HttpClient` to do calls to other APIs within my API controllers. According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0), I should only have one `HttpClient` instance because it causes a socket exhaust error.

However, I am currently creating one `HttpClient` per API controller. Should I make a `static` utility class instead that contains the single `HttpClient` or should I keep what I have? Is there a better alternative or a best practice when working with API controllers that themselves call other APIs?

If more information is required, please let me know.

Comment: [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method recommended to use httpclient is to use `IHttpClientFactory` and `Dependency Inject`.

Using the `IHttpClientFactory` has several benefits, including managing the lifetime of the network connections. Using the factory to create the client reuses connection from a connection pool, thereby not creating too many sockets. The connections are reused and automatically disposed to avoid DNS level issues.

By using `IHttpClientFactory`, we can solve all the initial issues that we saw with instantiating the `HttpClient` instance directly. After refactoring it to the Typed client consumption pattern, it is also well separated and easier to maintain. It drives us to write cleaner, loosely coupled code.

You can read these two articles([1](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/are-you-using-httpclient-in-the-right-way/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20IHttpClientFactory%20has%20several%20benefits%2C%20including%20managing,and%20automatically%20disposed%20to%20avoid%20DNS%20level%20issues.), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)) to learn more.

Comment: I see. So we need to add a new httpclient per external API endpoint in the Program.cs. I believe in .NET 6, it would be something like `builder.Services.AddHttpClient(...)`. Then, in each API controller instance the `IHTTPClientFactory` with `Dependency Injection` and call these external APIs simply using the name we used when adding them in Program.cs. Is this correct?

Comment: You can just use `builder.Services.AddHttpClient();` to register once for all endpoint, But If you need to set Base address for each endpoint, You can also use `builder.Services.AddHttpClient(...)` to add a new httpclient per external API endpoint.

Comment: I am upgrading from legacy asp.net web API 2 to core. I was using HttpWebRequest and it is obsolete. I am calling 3 different 3rd party web services. Which consumption pattern should I use? Would you help me?